# Creating a Nested Structure Table

Tags: google-bigquery, presto, amazon-athena

I want to create arrays of nested structure for my database

something like this :

```
array(row(item row(departmentNumber bigint, itemNumber bigint, shelfCapacity row(qty double, precision   bigint)) 

location row(zone varchar, aisle bigint)))
```

Below error i am facing:

But it's giving me error like this:

```
Unknown type: ROW(departmentNumber bigint, itemNumber bigint,shelfCapacity ROW )
```

I created a sample SQL

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[
    CAST(ROW('departmentNumber', 'itemNumber', CAST(ROW('qty', 'precision') AS ROW(qty double, precision bigint))) AS ROW(departmentNumber bigint, itemNumber bigint,shelfCapacity ROW ))
  ] AS items
)
SELECT * FROM dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 percent sure why identifier like 'departmentNumber' gets duplicated in your syntax, but in BigQuery, the `ROW` is called `STRUCT`, your query could likely be rewritten as:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[
    STRUCT<departmentNumber int64, itemNumber int64,shelfCapacity STRUCT<qty float64, precision int64>> (
      1, 1, STRUCT(2.1, 100)), 
      (2, 2, STRUCT(3.1, 200))
  ] AS items
)
SELECT * FROM dataset
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
 CAST(
        ROW(
          100,
          500,
              ROW(40.5, 60)
      ) AS 
        ROW(
          departmentNumber bigint,
          itemNumber bigint,
          shelfCapacity ROW(qty double, precision bigint)
     )
)
```